# distributed system with ZeroMQ?

Tags: zeromq, publish-subscribe

Can I have a distributed Zeromq server with a pubusb arquitecture ? I mean a load balancing but using pub sub all subcribers connected to a router instead of a single server ? I've read about but they do it balancing on the client but I want to do it on the server.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, please revise with more details.

Comment: You want to load-balance messages from server to clients using pub/sub and ROUTER socket?

Comment: like req/rep pattern using a router but not connected to the server in fact

Answer (score 1):

The PUB / SUB pattern can not be load balanced, simply since the subsriber decides which messages he gets and then he gets all of these. Think of pub-sub as multicast. From the guide (http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#toc114)

> PUB sends each message to "all of many", whereas PUSH and DEALER
>   rotate messages to "one of many".

Probably what you are after is a PUSH-PULL architecture.

Answer (score 0):

ROUTER-to-DEALER socket combination on the server distributes messages round-robin style to clients. The clients can be DEALER, ROUTER, or REP.

Pub/sub will not work because it does not load balance messages.

**Client-side Scaling**
Using ROUTER/DEALER on the server, you can add more clients dynamically; the server will automatically round robin to new clients.

Comment: Yep that's what I want. but how can I make my system scale with that architecture?